# Visual Studio - Registration of the app failed after uninstalling app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I am developing a Universal Windows 10 app and I get an annoying problem every time I try to run project after I uninstall the app from windows start menu. The scenario is:

1. I run project on local machine - app is running good;
2. I press Shift+F5 to stop runing;
3. Go to Windows start menu and uninstall just installed app;
4. Run app again from Visual Studio;
5. Get  error `1>Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. An internal error occurred with error 0x80073D05. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues. (0x80073cf6)`

**NOTE**: sometimes *Clean Solution* + *Rebuild Solution* helps, but sometimes only system restart solves the problem. Is this an official bug or I am missing something?

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the similar problem, and as per this link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/566e53ec-2020-4969-9f17-f0a5a916f027/error-dep0700-registration-of-the-app-failed?forum=winappswithcsharp

we need to locate the app`s package in  C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Packages and delete it. This error occurs when after installing if the system is not able to delete the complete package from Local.

Comment: Had an issue with the error code 0x80073D05 and this fixed my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the official bug in this case.

Please check if your project is build before and then deployed (please see screenshots below) and let me know whether problem remains and what is the version of the Windows platfrom you use.
You can check it using search window and type "winver":

[image]

[image]

[image]